# Ajax post call not calling after idle time of 5 minutes in FF

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax post call not hitting in FF after idle time of 5 minutes its working in chrome and IE but the problem in FF only, below is the my ajax call code.If I work on page continuously its working properly

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: URL,
       data: Form25,
       success: function (result) {
             window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ClientInformation", "Agent")";
       },
       error: function () {
             alert("error in binding the data");
       }
});
```

please can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here

If I put `async:false` its working but page is not navigating

Comment: What is the point of making an ajax call and then immediately redirecting?

Comment: after executing the url action method when it is successful I am redirecting to the ClientInformation

Comment: Yes I know. But why? If your wanting to redirect after a post, then do a standard submit to a controller method and use `return RedirectToAction("ClientInformation", "Agent");` Then  you also have the option of returning the view with `ModelState` errors. Your use of ajax is unnecessary and pointless

Comment: If I put async:false its working but page is not navigating

Comment: here some of my controls are auto generated so  i am not able to use submit to controller

Comment: What has that go to do with it. Your posting to a method using ajax so you can post to the same method using a normal submit

Comment: If user add textbox how can i give model to that textbox

Comment: If it has a name attribute that matches a model property then it will be bound to your model, or you can just add additional parameters to the post method. If your doing it with ajax then you can do it with a normal submit. But all this is not really associated with your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I expect your browser either isn't sending back a 200 response or jQuery is expecting a JSON object to be returned and you're not satisfying this condition.

You can try

- Inspecting the response to make sure it returns a 200 response header
- Inspecting the contents of the response body to check for errors
- Changing your MVC method signature to something like to make sure you return a valid JSON response.

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult ClientInformation(ClientInformationModel model)
  {
      [...]

      return Json(new object());
  }
  ```

Comment: It not even hits the url controller @dubs